メンバー関数ポインターのstd::map型のエラーを解消したい
Using a STL map of function pointers - Stack Overflow に書いてあるコードをメンバー関数についてしたいのですが、以下のエラーで困っています。ご教授いただければと思います。
C2064 引数を取り込む関数には評価されません。

現状のコード:
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <cassert>
    
class Test
{
public:
    // every function pointer will be stored as this type
    typedef void (Test::*voidFunctionType)(void);

    struct Interface {

        std::map<std::string, std::pair<voidFunctionType, std::type_index>> m1;

        template<typename T>
        void insert(std::string s1, T f1) {
            auto tt = std::type_index(typeid(f1));
            m1.insert(std::make_pair(s1,
                std::make_pair((voidFunctionType)f1, tt)));
        }

        template<typename T, typename... Args>
        T searchAndCall(std::string s1, Args&&... args) {
            auto mapIter = m1.find(s1);
            /*chk if not end*/
            auto mapVal = mapIter->second;

            // auto typeCastedFun = reinterpret_cast<T(*)(Args ...)>(mapVal.first); 
            auto typeCastedFun = (T(Test::*)(Args ...))(mapVal.first);

            //compare the types is equal or not
            assert(mapVal.second == std::type_index(typeid(typeCastedFun)));
            return typeCastedFun(std::forward<Args>(args)...); //C2064
        }
    };

    void fun1(void) {
        std::cout << "inside fun1\n";
    };

    int fun2() {
        std::cout << "inside fun2\n";
        return 2;
    };

    int fun3(int a) {
        std::cout << "inside fun3\n";
        return a;
    };

    std::vector<int> fun4() {
        std::cout << "inside fun4\n";
        std::vector<int> v(4, 100);
        return v;
    };

};

int main() {
    Test::Interface a1;
    a1.insert("fun1", &Test::fun1);
    a1.insert("fun2", &Test::fun2);
    a1.insert("fun3", &Test::fun3);
    a1.insert("fun4", &Test::fun4);

    a1.searchAndCall<void>("fun1");
    int retVal = a1.searchAndCall<int>("fun3", 2);
    a1.searchAndCall<int>("fun2");
    auto temp = a1.searchAndCall<std::vector<int>>("fun4");

    return 0;
}


Testメンバー関数ポインターを呼び出すにはthisポインターとなるTestインスタンスが必要です。
つまり、通常の呼び出しであれば
Test t;
t.fun1();

になるわけで、

return typeCastedFun(std::forward<Args>(args)...); //C2064


の部分も
Test t;
return std::invoke(typeCastedFun, t, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

等にする必要があります。現実的には Test::Interface::searchAndCall() が Test& などを受け取るとかでしょうか。

ありがとうございます。解決しました。
